# How to change dataset value before bind to grid view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dataset

I have Data set In form of like this in `asp.net`. i Bind that in Grid view But i want to change value to 1= good and 2 = Bad before show in grid.

**`A 1 1 1 1`**

**`B 1 1 2 1`**

But i want to print like

**`A Good Good Good Good`**

**`B Good Bad  Good Good`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this condition in your gridview. You will have to use `TemplateField` for this:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdTest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
  <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField>
          <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" 
                                  Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                          Text='<%# Eval("Id1") == "1" ? "Good" : "Bad" %>'>/asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: But if i have 3 or 4 values than how can i apply that?

Comment: @VivekPatel - In that case, you should write you logic while populating the dataset itself. Either in SQL or populating a list or any other data source.

Comment: I'm using mysql database did you have any idea how to do in mysql.

Comment: @VivekPatel - You can use `CASE` statement or if else in SQL database, and based on values return specific value. I think you are a newbie, better refer some articles or tutorials rather. SO is only for specific code problems.